# Prove or disprove: $\exists x \forall y \,\,\varphi \models \forall y \exists x \,\ \varphi$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

> Prove or disprove: $\exists x \forall y \,\,\varphi \models \forall y
> \exists x \,\ \varphi$
>
> where $\varphi$ is a first-order-logic formula

About notation: I call LHS as $A$ and RHS as $B$. Then $A \models B$ means that $B$ is true in every structure in wich $A$ is true. Now question is if this is the case here, with proof.

Let's say we have $\varphi : = R(x,y)$ where $R$ stands for relation.

Then LHS says that

> For some $x$, all $y$ are such that $R(x,y)$

RHS says that

> For any $y$, there is a $x$ such that $R(x,y)$

Now if we expand those two sentences, we have for LHS:

> There exists a $x \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for any number $y$, we have that $x
> >y$. This is wrong because there can't be number that is greater than
>   all numbers.

For RHS we have:

> For any $y \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a number $x$ such that $x >
> y$. This is correct because for any number there is always a bigger
>   number.

---

For this reason we have no model here and this means the statement is false.

I like to know if this is correct pls because I need it for exam and I would do it like that in exam if they ask similar question?

Comment: What do you get for proving the LHS wrong?

Comment: If the premises is *false* the relation holds vacuously. The def of $\vDash$ says: tehre is **no** model of the premises where the consequence is false.

Comment: @conime You probably mean $>$ instead of $<$ in your model.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thank you because I made this yellow I accidently delete wrong sign

Comment: @conime if it is true, what method do you have to use to prove it? A semantical one, like the one you just did, or can you do a syntactical one, like a formal proof?

Comment: @Bram28 Both allowed, I ask teacher how prove it because this is from an old exam and they don't want show it in class and rather do other things in class, that's why I ask here. She told me you can easily do it by induction but I don't see how.. It must be easier than induction

Comment: @conime Induction?!?  Anyway, do you think the implication holds or not? You showed that the B does not imply A, but do you think A implies B?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes I was shocked too when I heard it was recommended.. "Induction on construction of formula" or something like that.. 

Anyway, yes I think the implication holds but I still don't have a proof for it, just a reason:

If we have some structure S for some language $L(x) = \left\{y \in L | L \models R(x,y)\right\}$ then when we have a point let's say $p \in S$ and put it into set $L(p)$ where everything satisfies relation $R$ with $p$

Then by RHS we know there must be any $y$ so $y \in L(p)$ forall $p$. Then from this we know that intersection of all $L(p) \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Bram28 Then LHS must imply RHS because as said intersection is not empty and then $L(p)$ not empty as well

Comment: @conime That sounds unnecessarily complicated ... .  As you said, if A is true then there is some x such that for all y R(x,y). OK, so let's call this x 'Bob'. So, 'Bob' stands in relation R to everything (including itself). But then it is true that for everything, there is something that stands in relation R to it (namely 'Bob'). So, B is true.

Comment: @Bram28 Real life example is really nice for understand it better but you think this will count as proof? I don't know they will allow it in exam or not maybe I better ask them or you know it already?

Comment: @conime Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to say that what you did is wrong. In fact, as a proof it is a bit more precise than what I just said. Yes, what you did is perfectly acceptable as a proof! And I'll post a syntactical formal proof in a little while myself

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you very much you always help me a lot when I ask question about logic task! :))

Thank you also for everyone who posted here!

Comment: @conime You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given $\exists x\forall y\;\varphi(x,y)$. So let $x_0$ be such that $\forall y\;\varphi(x_0,y)$. In particular,  for arbitrary $y$, we have $\varphi(x_0,y)$.

Now let $y$ be arbitrary. As just seen, we have $\varphi(x_0,y)$, hence $\exists x\;\varphi(x,y)$. As $y$ was arbitrary, $\forall y\exists x\;\varphi(x,y)$, as was to be shown.

Answer (score 4):

All you have done so far is to show one particular structure in which $A$ is false and $B$ is true. This tells you nothing about $A\vDash B$, which is about structures where $A$ is *true*. It *does not care* what might happen to $B$ in structures that *don't* satisfy $A$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that correct. Would my solution be correct if we were looking for $B \models A$? If this is wrong I really don't know what to do for this example : /

Comment: @conime: Yes, your argument does disprove $B\vDash A$. Since $\exists x \forall y \,\,\varphi \models \forall y
\exists x \,\ \varphi$ is alctually true, you should be looking for a proof rather than a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

'Informal semantical proof': If A is true then there is some $x$ such that for all $y$ such that $R(x,y)$. OK, so let's call this x 'Bob'. So, 'Bob' stands in relation $R$ to everything (including itself). But then it is true that for everything, there is something that stands in relation $R$ to it (namely 'Bob'!). So, for all $y$ there is some $x$ such that $R(x,y)$. So, B is true.

And here is a formal proof in Fitch:

[image]